# NTP under firewall can't open udp port 123

Tags: time, server, synchronization, ntp

My server is in the co-location which restricted outbound udp port.

Is there anyway to sync server time without open UDP 123 port?

Answer (score 0):

If NTP over UDP is blocked then you can use a GPS receiver or other protocols such as HTTP. For example, You can use [HTTP Time Protocol / htpdate](http://www.vervest.org/htp/). It's not a good time source as compared to NTP, but might be good enough.

> The htpdate utility retrieves the date and time from remote web
> servers via the network. Htpdate works through proxy servers as it
> behaves similar to a web browser. Accuracy of htpdate will be usually
> within 500 milliseconds.

Alternatively, for less than $30 on Amazon you can get a USB GPS receiver. Some products include software to sync host computer's clock and/or drivers for NTP.